# Unificar archivos en un data frame en r

Tags: funciones, r

Intento unificar archivos (cuyos nombres son `001.csv`,...,`332.csv`)con el siguiente for:

```
files.together<- function(directory,id=1:332) {
        files<-list.files(path = directory,full.names = T)
        values<-numeric()
        for(i in id){
                data<-read.csv(files[i])
                values<-rbind(values,data)
        }
        write.csv(x = values,file = "data.csv")
        data<-read.csv(file.path(getwd(),"data.csv"),header = T)
}
```

Funciona muy bien, excepto la última línea, donde lo que intento hacer es que cargue automáticamente el nuevo archivo unificado que ha sido creado con el for

Comment: ¿Y tu pregunta es?

Comment: mi pregunta es cómo corregir la última línea : "data<-read.csv(file.path(getwd(),"data.csv"),header = T)" puesto que no lo hace. Tengo que cargar el nuevo archivo "data.csv" normalmente, cuando quisiera que la función lo haga por mí

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no lo está haciendo? Dentro de la función, en la última línea, puedes poner `return(data)` e invocar a la función así: `datos = files.together('directorio/donde/estan/los/csv')` Lo demás dependerá de cómo estén separados los csv, de si tienen cabecero,... Pero no aportas esa información.

Answer (score 0):

Podés evitar el uso de un bucle `for` usando funciones de la familia `apply` de la siguiente forma:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = directory, pattern = "[0-3][0-9]{2}.csv")
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(filenames, read.csv))
write.csv(df, file = "unificado.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

En el caso que quieras pasar parámetros a la función `read.csv` sería de la siguiente forma (suponiendo que archivo `csv` está separado por `;`)

```
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(filenames, read.csv, sep = ";"))
```